# Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 CA in different hosts

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I already read de hyperledger read docs about the CA in Fabric 1.0, http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Setup/ca-setup.html?highlight=ca, but I can't understand how will work the CA if I need to run tow CAs, in same Blockchain, in different organizations. All docker file that I sow don't have a example that run in different hosts, in different organizations.

Any can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be more than one CA Server. For example, each organization can have it's own CA Server.

Once you have initialized all your CA servers you need, you have to get the root certificates. That's possible thanks to the *fabric-ca-client getcacerts* command.

More info at: http://hyperledger-fabric-ca.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users-guide.html#getting-a-ca-certificate-chain-from-another-fabric-ca-server